# How to change arrow direction of mat-expansion-indicator

Tags: angular-material

I am using material's Mat expansion in my angular project. There is default arrow direction of mat-expansion-indictor. I want to change the direction of arrow and on click it should rotate 180 degrees.

There are few ways of doing it with !important OR ng::deep but i don't want to use any of these as its not a good practice to use these.

Please help me in implementing clear solution to change arrow direction.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please provide some code so that we can assist you.